# How do I set the volt compiled directory path in Phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon

I have the following code:

```
    $di->set('view', function() {

    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();

    $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');

    $view->registerEngines(array(
        ".phtml" => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt'
    ));

    return $view;
});
```

But now the compiled PHP lives in the views directory. How can I set a different path for the compiled directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the new `compiledPath` and other options as follows:

Assume that you have these variables in your config:

```
[views]
path      = '/home/user/www/app/views/'

[volt]
path      = '/home/user/www/app/volt/'
extension = '.compiled'
separator = '%%'
stat      = 1
```

You can then do this according to the manual:

```
// Assuming that this is in a class and `_di` is your DI container 
$config = $this->_di->get('config');
$di     = $this->_di;

/**
 * Setup the volt service
 */
$this->_di->set(
    'volt',
    function($view, $di) use($config)
    {
        $volt = new Volt($view, $di);
        $volt->setOptions(
            array(
                'compiledPath'      => $config->app->volt->path,
                'compiledExtension' => $config->app->volt->extension,
                'compiledSeparator' => $config->app->volt->separator,
                'stat'              => (bool) $config->app->volt->stat,
            )
        );
        return $volt;
    }
);

/**
 * Setup the view service
 */
$this->_di->set(
    'view',
    function() use ($config, $di)
    {
        $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
        $view->setViewsDir(ROOT_PATH . $config->app->path->views);
        $view->registerEngines(array('.volt' => 'volt'));
        return $view;
    }
);
```

or you can follow the implementation below (the above one is preferred)

```
$di->set('view', function() use ($config, $di) {

    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();

    $view->setViewsDir($config->views->path);

    $volt = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt($view, $di);

    $volt->setOptions(
        array(
            'compiledPath'      => $config->volt->path,
            'compiledExtension' => $config->volt->extension,
            'compiledSeparator' => $config->volt->separator,
            'stat'              => (bool) $config->volt->stat,
        )
    );

    /**
     * Register Volt
     */
    $view->registerEngines(array('.volt' => $volt));

    return $view;
});
```

Make sure that your `$config->volt->path` is writeable. You don't need to follow exactly the approach above - you can always substitute the configuration variables with whatever your application needs.

Comment: I get: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt::setOptions() in /var/www/html/phalconblog/public/index.php on line 59`

Comment: Please recompile the extension. I had the same issue with the code when I was testing the above.

Comment: @netstu have a look at the answer again please. I edited it with the correct/preferred syntax.